# why are the newline characters in my json file showing up as the character "n"

Tags: android, json

I have a android app thats supposed to fetch a json file from the web and pars it.
I uploaded the json file onto my website as direct file with the extension .json

my app fetches this file, but when I print out its contents, anywhere where there should be a newline character, there is a "n" instead, and naturally the json parser doesnt like this and I get an exception.

UPDATE:
after looking at my code that parses the input stream I found the problem:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
```

for some reason, in this code, which was working flawlessly for my other app, I am appending "n" instead on "\n"!!! I wonder if I deleted the backslash by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to escape the slash character by using

> `\\n`

inside the json.

Later on you can use this code for parsing the string from json,

```
public String escapeJavaString(String st) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(st.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
        char ch = st.charAt(i);
        if (ch == '\\') {
            char nextChar = (i == st.length() - 1) ? '\\' : st
                    .charAt(i + 1);
            // Octal escape?
            if (nextChar >= '0' && nextChar <= '7') {
                String code = "" + nextChar;
                i++;
                if ((i < st.length() - 1) && st.charAt(i + 1) >= '0'
                        && st.charAt(i + 1) <= '7') {
                    code += st.charAt(i + 1);
                    i++;
                    if ((i < st.length() - 1) && st.charAt(i + 1) >= '0'
                            && st.charAt(i + 1) <= '7') {
                        code += st.charAt(i + 1);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                sb.append((char) Integer.parseInt(code, 8));
                continue;
            }
            switch (nextChar) {
            case '\\':
                ch = '\\';
                break;
            case 'b':
                ch = '\b';
                break;
            case 'f':
                ch = '\f';
                break;
            case 'n':
                ch = '\n';
                break;
            case 'r':
                ch = '\r';
                break;
            case 't':
                ch = '\t';
                break;
            case '\"':
                ch = '\"';
                break;
            case '\'':
                ch = '\'';
                break;
            // Hex Unicode: u????
            case 'u':
                if (i >= st.length() - 5) {
                    ch = 'u';
                    break;
                }
                int code = Integer.parseInt(
                        "" + st.charAt(i + 2) + st.charAt(i + 3)
                                + st.charAt(i + 4) + st.charAt(i + 5), 16);
                sb.append(Character.toChars(code));
                i += 5;
                continue;
            }
            i++;
        }
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Have a look [here](http://udojava.com/2013/09/28/unescape-a-string-that-contains-standard-java-escape-sequences/) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you have to escape the slash character. 
That is in your website you should put `"\\n"` inside the json object for each new line.