# Eliminating Unicode Characters and Escape Characters from String

Tags: java, unicode

I want to remove all Unicode Characters and Escape Characters like `(\n, \t)` etc. In short I want just alphanumeric string.

For example :

`\u2029My Actual String\u2029
\nMy Actual String\n`

I want to fetch just `'My Actual String'`. Is there any way to do so, either by using a built in string method or a Regular Expression ?

Comment: This was asked 5 mins ago, what are the odds ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678238/converting-unicode-to-string-java

Comment: Look here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20654784/2968614

Comment: That was just for '/n' but I want for both Unicode and escape characters Actually I am done but in java '/' is replaced by '//' that's why my RE or Function is not working.

Comment: To remove all Unicode characters from a string, you just need to remove *everything* from the string. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
String  stg = "\u2029My Actual String\u2029 \nMy Actual String";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?!(\\\\(u|U)\\w{4}|\\s))(\\w)+");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(stg);
String out  =  "";
while(mat.find()){
    out+=mat.group()+" ";   
}
System.out.println(out);
```

The regex matches all things except unicode and escape characters. The regex pictorially represented as:

[image]

*Output*:

```
My Actual String My Actual String
```

Comment: how '\n' or '\t' runs in this flow ?

Comment: `\s` stands for "whitespace character". Again, which characters this actually includes, depends on the regex flavor. [ \t\r\n\f]. That is: `\s` matches a space, a tab, a line break, or a form feed.

Comment: What if I just want to remove all these characters just from the start of string for example \u2029 \\t\\t&*^ my Actual String ==> my Actual String ???

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
anyString = anyString.replaceAll("\\\\u\\d{4}|\\\\.", "");
```

to remove escaped characters. If you also want to remove all other special characters use this one:

```
anyString = anyString.replaceAll("\\\\u\\d{4}|\\\\.|[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "");
```

(I guess you want to keep the whitespaces, if not remove `\\s` from the one above)

Comment: Actually I also written RE but it was not replacing the unicode characters because in Java '\' is replaced with '\\'.